# Getting values of keys from a rdd of maps in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, rdd

I have an RDD which has maps as its elements. I cannot use RDD.get, of course. So, as of now, I do the following to get values for keys from this map:

```
val x = RDD.collect().flatten.toMap
```

and then

```
x.get(key)
```

to get the value for the key. Now, have a really big rdd which outputs the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` as I am applying .collect() on the rdd. How can I do it without applying .collect() on the rdd?

Comment: can you share a reproducible example including expected output?

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that you are calling collect  (an "action") far too early. You need to transform your RDD into a (hopefully) smaller RDD -- basically you just want those elements with the desired key -- and then call collect at the last moment when you have only a few elements in your RDD.

Answer (score 3):

If it is truly `Map`s then you can do the following:

```
rdd.flatMap(identity).lookup(key)
```

Although this will still output to the driver, but only the values from that key. So, if that can fit in memory then you are good with that. But if you want to work with it as an rdd still then:

```
rdd.flatMap(identity)
   .flatMap{case (key, value) => if(key == myKey) Some(value) else None}
```

And should you want key AND value then you can turn the `flatMap` into a filter and just filter on `key == myKey`

Comment: I did not know about `lookup`, that's clearly the right feature to use here. However, your second `flatMap` looks a lot like a `filter`...

Comment: Thanks @CyrilleCorpet I modified the answer to be explicit why I chose flatMap, but gave filter a callout just in case.

Comment: @JustinPihony, the above method works but then I have to use "rdd.flatMap(identity).lookup(key)" inside another rdd say rdd2. For each element of rdd2, I have to look up its value in "rdd". The error thrown was, This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: (1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't fit everything onto your driver, you first need to filter the RDD for the map you need to look into, and then do the get...

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Map("a"->1,"b"->2),Map("c"->3,"d"->4)))

val key = "d"

val filteredRDD = rdd.filter(_.keySet contains key)

if (!filteredRDD.isEmpty) filteredRDD.first.get(key) else None
```